# D3 - mouse event handling on a map

Tags: dictionary, event-handling, d3.js

I am working on drawing a map and attaching mouse events on it. I am using D3 library.

I registered mouse event handlers to "counties path (each county)" using D3's "on" function. It needs to print out log on console (i.e., console log) when happening mouse events, but it is not working.

The below is the whole code. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.v2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.geo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

#counties path {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .25px;  

}

/*
#counties path:hover {
  stroke: yellow;
  fill: orange;
}
*/

#map_legend {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="body">
        <div id = "map_legend">

<script type="text/javascript">


var width = 960, 
    height = 500,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().scale(960*4).translate([800,-50]); 
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#map_legend").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 80) //960
    .attr("height", 130);  //500

var counties = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
   .append("g")
    .attr("id", "counties");


  d3.json("us-counties.json", function(json) {
    counties.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("id",function(d,i) { return i;})
        .attr("d", path);
  });


counties.selectAll("path")
    //.attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {  console.log("path mouseover"); }) 
    .on("mouseout", function(d) { console.log("path mouseout"); }) 
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {  console.log("path mouseout");})
    .on("touchmove", function(d) { console.log("path mouseout"); })
    .on("click", function(d) { console.log("path click"); });



    </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the asynchronous call to `d3.json`. You are trying to establish the mouse event listeners before there are any paths to select and establish them on. Try moving the code block that sets up the listeners into the callback of `d3.json`.

Comment: Thank you very much! After moving the code block into the callback of d3.json, it works!